# symfony1.4 PDO queries to web debug bar

Tags: sql, debugging, symfony-1.4

I'm executing some complex queries in my app "by hand" via PDO, using

```
$pdo = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();
```

These queries do not appear in the symfony web debug bar. How can I add them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into `lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\debug\sfWebDebugPanelDoctrine.class.php`. It seems that there is a Doctrine_Connection_Profiler (`sfDoctrineConnectionProfiler`) which list method to handle event on a query.

Each queries seems to be an event.